# Trick to apply function on a variable and store output in the same variable

Tags: function-construction

Is there any Mathematica shorthand notation for this

```
var=AnyFunction[var]
```

Where I apply a function on the variable `var` and want to store the output in the same variable.

Comment: Why can't you just do this?  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdPmX.png)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there is [`ApplyTo`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ApplyTo.html) with a shorthand notation `//=`.

```
var //= AnyFunction
```

Comment: This does not store the result back in the variable, which is what OP wanted.  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmE7E.png)

Comment: @Nasser You wrote `x // foo` instead of `x //= foo`

Comment: @LukasLang opps, you are right. I never used this // before. Ok, sorry, it works.